# Merging based on multiple ranges

Tags: r, data.table, sqldf

I would like to merge two data-frames on multiple ranges. Below I have produced a representative example. The sqldf solution works, however, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this (e.g., using data.table).

```
base <- data.frame(lower1 = c(12, 12, 3, 2), upper1 = c(20, 20, 20, 4), 
                   lower2 = c(12, 12, 3, 2), upper2 = c(20, 20, 20, 4)) %>% 
  data.table()

more_info <- data.frame(color = 'red', value1 = 4, value2 = 4, thing1 = 5, thing2 = 5) %>% 
  data.table()

setkey(base,      lower1, upper1, lower2, upper2)
setkey(more_info, value1, value2, thing1, thing2)

# works
sqldf('select * from base left join more_info
      on (    base.lower1 <= more_info.value1 and base.upper1 >= more_info.value1
          and base.lower2 <= more_info.thing1 and base.upper2 >= more_info.thing1)')

# doesn't work but is what i would like to do
setkey(base,      lower1, upper1, lower2, upper2)
setkey(more_info, value1, value2, thing1, thing2)

foverlaps(more_info, base, by.x = key(more_info), by.y = key(base), type = 'within', 
          mult = 'all', nomatch = NA)
```

As a little bit of background, I have a matching algorithm that I need to improve run-times for. The matching algorithm works by filtering down a large number of loans based on certain characteristics to a smaller number of potential matches. Then, I apply whatever additional statistical techniques are necessary to find the best match. The hold-up is repeatedly filtering down the large data set of all matches to a smaller number of potential matches. My goal is to find a faster way to create the data-frame of potential matches and then use a group-by and other vectorized functions to complete the matching process.

Comment: The `between` keyword in SQL can be used to shorten the conditions.  `setkey` is part of data.table, not sqldf.  `create index` is available in SQL to set indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
more_info[base, .(lower1, upper1, lower2, upper2, color, value1 = x.value1, 
                       value2 = x.value2, thing1 = x.thing1, thing2 = x.thing2), 
          on = .(value1 >= lower1, value1 <= upper1, thing1 >= lower2, thing1 <= upper2)]
```

Output:

```
   lower1 upper1 lower2 upper2 color value1 value2 thing1 thing2
1:     12     20     12     20  <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA
2:     12     20     12     20  <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA
3:      3     20      3     20   red      4      4      5      5
4:      2      4      2      4  <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: not sure why this answer isn't accepted yet.. benchmarking shows this solution is about 10x faster than the sqldf....

Comment: I also don't think there's a much faster solution in R, but probably OP is just new to SO and doesn't know how it functions.